# Should I use SharePoint Number column types to store monetary values?

Tags: number

In SharePoint I can create a list column of type 'Number'. I need to store monetary amounts and would like to be able to use this column type rather than having to create a new one.

Are values of this type stored and manipulated by SharePoint (e.g. when summing values in a list view) to prevent loss of precision (i.e. not as some kind of approximate floating point type)?

I have looked at currency columns but they seem to force display of a currency unit which doesn't make sense in my application (and I have a suspicion that they are stored as 'Numbers' under the bonnet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [answer to this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687651/should-i-use-sharepoint-number-column-types-to-store-monetary-values/1723917#1723917).

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this and found the following:

- number and currency are the same, just formatted differently
- they are stored in the database as the [SQL float data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)
- using any more decimal places than 1.00000001 rounds the value in the UI
- using any more decimal places than 1.00000000000001 rounds the value in the database

While they are stored as `float` in the DB, there is no way to find out how they are handled internally within the application. It's important to test this for your use case to be sure!

(Note: while I have made database queries here to research your question, please do not do this in anything other than a development environment.)